# How to Identify last element in an Array in Dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

i have a dataweave expression to create a custom String , but i do not want to append || to the last element of the input array . How can i achieve it ?

```
    %dw 2.0
    output application/json
    var arr = ["ABC","XYZ"]
    ---
    arr  map((item,index) -> {
        index: "custom ('" ++ item ++ "'); " ++ "||"
    })
```

Comment: Would you like to append || to the last element of the array, for a given array that is?

Comment: No i does not want to append the || for the last element , but it has to be there in all other element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this help?

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var arr = ["ABC","XYZ"]
---
arr  map((item,index) -> {
    index: if((index) < (sizeOf(arr)-1)) "custom ('" ++ item ++ "'); " ++ "||" else item
})
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "index": "custom ('ABC'); ||"
  },
  {
    "index": "XYZ"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try with the following:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var arr = ["ABC","XYZ"]
---
take(arr,(sizeOf(arr)-1)) map (
     $ ++ "||" // do your manipulation to modify the custom entry
)
```

`take` is documented [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-arrays-functions-take)

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, are you then taking this resulting array and joining it into a string? Your question seems to indicate the end goal of the function is returning a string. If you are, you can just `map` and then `joinBy`

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var arr = ["ABC","XYZ", "DKJL"]
---
arr map "custom($($));" joinBy " || "
```

Outputs

```json
"custom(ABC); || custom(XYZ); || custom(DKJL);"
```

And if like in Salim's answer you shouldn't be wrapping the last value in custom, you could also take advantage of the default behavior of reduce:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var arr = ["ABC","XYZ", "DKJL"]
---
arr[-1 to 0] reduce ("custom($($)); || " ++ $$)
```

Outputs

```json
"custom(ABC); || custom(XYZ); || DKJL"
```